# Communicate two ionic - angular apps through node server

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I have two Ionic applications, and both use the same API served with node. What I need is that when one app sends a post request, the other app gets that post request and uses the information that comes from the request. How can I achieve this? I thought of listening for that particular post request, but I don't know if that's possible, or when the post request reaches the API, trigger some action in the server that sends the information to the other app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to implement this.

When one ionic application requests a service from your server by using HTTP Requests, the server will trigger the respective action and sends a push notification to your other app by using the Firebase cloud messaging service. Your 2nd app will capture this push notification by subscribing to a URL in Firebase.

For the server-side, You can use [fcm-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node) module or Firebase NodeJS Module to implement this functionality. For the mobile app, you can use providers in ionic to subscribe to firebase cloud messages

A detailed guide on implementing push notifications can be found [here](https://medium.com/hirewithparam/independent-notification-service-using-ionic-node-fcm-5cdde219480a)